# Compiling model as executable for faster inference?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, inference

Is there a way to compile the entire Python script with my trained model for faster inference? Seems like loading the Python interpreter, all of Tensorflow, numpy, etc. takes a non-trivial amount of time. When this has to happen at a server responding to a non-trivial frequency of requests, it seems slow.

**Edit**

I know I can use Tensorflow serving, but don't want to because of the costs associated with it.

Comment: Why not just listen for signals and use a daemon with the model already loaded to load the request and then produce a formatted response?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I'm cool with that. Do you have information on how I can set that up? Python novice here...

Comment: I would honestly probably do this as a server daemon using Twisted. A simple, specialized example is. You should be able to specialize this to load JSON data, and then use your code with Tensorflow already loaded to process it and then process it to format a response:
https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/08/twisted-web-post-example-json/

Comment: Please note the command is "twistd", not "twisted" I believe for recent versions of it. I might be completely butchering the naming.

Comment: Look up XLA AOT compilation, it turns your TF model into binary with C API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you set up a server? If you are setting up a server using python framework like django, flask or tornado, you just need to preload your model and keep it as a global variable, and then use this global variable to predict.

If you are using some other server. You can also make the entire python script you use to predict as a local server, and transform request or response between python server and web server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to only serve the tensorflow model, or are you doing any work outside of tensorflow?

For just the tensorflow model, you could use [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/). If you are comfortable with [gRPC](https://grpc.io/), this will serve you quite well.